# python matplotlib hist not showing missing bin properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, bins

I have a dataframe that is constructed with numbers from 1 to 16, but without number 15.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rand_int_no_15':[random.choice([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16]) for cnt in range(100) ]})
```

Now I would like to display histogram in which I will see that there is no number 15.
In order to do so, I have executed

```
df.rand_int_no_15.hist(bins=np.arange(1, df.rand_int_no_15.max() + 1))
```

[image]

but, what I got is histogram from which I cannot conclude that number 15 doesn't exist.
I would have expected that bar above number 15 is empty.

Am I doing something wrongly?

Regards.

Comment: Are you sure you want a histogram and not a bar chart?

Comment: The rightmost bin in numpy/matplotlib histograms is closed. Hence you need `bins=np.arange(1, df.rand_int_no_15.max() + 2)`

Comment: It works as you suggested. If I use align='left' (I don't know why but) then each number is between its bar.

df.rand_int_no_15.hist(bins=np.arange(1, df.rand_int_no_15.max() + 2), align='left')